# Is it possible to put commands in /etc/motd?

Tags: linux, motd

Can I put shell commands in the `/etc/motd` login banner file? I have tried:

```
 $(uptime)
```

and

```
`uptime`
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`/etc/motd` is only read and not executed, so technically speaking, you cannot put shell commands in there.

However, it's possible to execute a shell script at login time that will have the same result.  This is usually achieved by adapting the `/etc/profile` script that is executed each time a user logs in.  A useful practice is to put the command you want to be executed in a script named `/etc/motd.sh` and call this script from `/etc/profile`, usually at about the end of it.

Comment: it's not a common practise to use /etc/motd.sh

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU Yes, one can use whatever script name he/she wants.  I just removed the _common_ adjective that was not appropriate.  Still, having it named this way makes it easy to spot and know what purpose it serves.

Comment: There seems to be a way of using cron to regularly replace the static motd message: http://www.md3v.com/create-a-linux-server-status-motd I think that this profile script seems to be a better way, less moving parts.

Comment: Putting output like a MOTD in your profile is likely to break sftp.

Comment: You can place the `motd.sh` script inside `/etc/profile.d/` with permissions `755`. This way you wouldn't need to call it from `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Using both `/etc/profile` and well as `/etc/profile.d` causes side effects of scripts being run NOT only during really first login (SSH/console) but also for example when you open a new `screen` window. The way to go is using PAM-based solution - see the other answers for them.

Answer (score 10):

In **Ubuntu** servers there is a program called [`update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) from package `libpam-modules`:

> UNIX/Linux system adminstrators often communicate important information
>          to console and remote users by maintaining text in the file  /etc/motd,
>          which  is  displayed  by  the  pam_motd(8)  module on interactive shell
>          logins.
>
> Traditionally, this file is static text,  typically  installed  by  the
>          distribution  and  only  updated on release upgrades, or overwritten by
>          the local administrator with pertinent information.
>
> Ubuntu introduced the update-motd framework, by which  the  motd(5)  is
>          dynamically assembled from a collection of scripts at login.

This collection of scripts lives under `/etc/update-motd.d/`. For more information see this [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd#Design).

Another alternative to generating `/etc/motd`, instead of having a script run at login is to have a cron job. Certainly, it is not the same, but I have met this approach sometimes in the past. Note however that this approach has been also used by `update-motd`, but it has been abandoned because of problem encountered. You can find a bit more info about this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/399071).

Comment: Related [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105689/how-is-etc-motd-updated). Force with `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`.

Comment: This also minimizes the startup login lag since you don't have to evaluate a script at login (assuming it gets more complex than `uptime`).

Answer (score 1):

For **Centos 7** servers I suggest using my port of `update-motd.d` from Ubuntu.

Unlike other solutions it makes the dynamic MOTD actually show only once, when you SSH / login through a console (other solutions make it show when you open new `screen` windows, for example).

Install it with:

```
yum install https://github.com/gdubicki/centos-pam-with-update-motd/releases/download/1.1.8-1022.3/pam-1.1.8-1022.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Use with:

1. Delete the default static `/etc/motd`.
2. Make SSHD not show the static MOTD with lines `PrintMotd   no`, `Banner      none`, `UsePAM      yes` (and optionally `PrintLastLog no`) in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` & reload `sshd` service.
3. Add this line to your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`: `session    optional     pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic`.
4. Add your scripts to `/etc/update-motd.d`, like on Ubuntu

Please see https://github.com/gdubicki/centos-pam-with-update-motd for the most up to date info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same in all distros, but on Arch Linux the `/etc/profile` file will already contain some content you usually don't want to touch. But you can create a new file in the `/etc/profile.d/` folder and fill it with the script you want to execute.

For example:

###### content of `/etc/profile.d/motd.sh`:

```
echo "Hello, we have the date and time: $(date)"
```

which outputs this text, when logging in:

```
Hello, we have the date and time: Tue Apr  4 00:53:11 CEST 2023
```